# Difference in Java and Vuforia Android SDK

Tags: android, vuforia

I have an android app developed using Java. I need some features of Vuforia SDK but it seems the coding language is different for Vuforia.

Can I add Vuforia AR Core features in my Java Code in Android? Or do I have to redevelop my entire App in Vuforia?

Comment: https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Getting-Started-with-Vuforia-for-Android-Development

Comment: This link is pointing to basics of Vuforia. I need to know whether we can include ARCore features using Java and Vuforia? Or do we need Unity Programming to bring ARCore Features?